# How to find the call site that changed an object being watched

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS allows listening for changes of an object and will call the supplied callback function supplied to the $watch function. With a largish library using AngularJS like ngGrid objects are frequently changed that's being "watched".

Once the watch callback is invoked, how can one trace back the call site that caused the change to the object?

Without knowing what caused the change, and so caused the watch handler to be invoked, it is proving very difficult to debug a library like ngGrid. I'm setting breakpoints everywhere I can foresee the variable could be changed, and then trying to build a graph for the execution pipeline to follow the chain of events that lead to an object being changed.

Comment: It may not solve all your problem but do you know **AngularJS Batarang**? It's a nice Chrome plugin that allows you to trace your applications models and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't do that. `$watch` will just add a callback to check whether the object changed, to be run during digests.

I guess that's one of the main differences with frameworks like `Backbone` where you extend a `Model` object.

That being said, you *might* have better luck trying to `$scope.$digest();` intentionally (updating the model, and firing the watchers), but it's a stretch...

#### Update

The problem is you're thinking there's a correlation between watches and model changes, but there simply isn't. Adding a watch just adds something to be checked when the digest loop runs.

This loop isn't triggered by changes to something on a `$scope`, but rather calls to `$scope.$apply`, or directly calling `$scope.$digest`.

Note that most *(all?)* of Angular's directives and related components call `$scope.$apply` on your behalf. For example, the reason why `$timeout` and `ngClick` work as expected, is because they run `$scope.$apply` internally after executing your callbacks.

#### Update II

If you're merely interested in finding the call site, could something like this help you?

```
$scope.foo = {
  get bar () { return getting(); },
  set bar (value) { setting(value); }
};

var bar;

function setting (value) {
  var stack = getStack();
  console.log(value, stack);
  bar = value;
}

function getting () {
  console.log(getStack());
}

function getStack () {
  try {
    throw new Error('foo');
  } catch (e) {
    return e.stack || e;
  }
}
```

[image: result.png]

Comment: I think my title was ambiguous so I've updated it, but I suspect the answer remains the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may have found the answer by now, but because I was looking for it, too, and could not find it so I am posting the answer here.

Let's assume your javascript variable is `name`, and you would like to find who changed that.

The method I have found is this:

1. Change `name` to `name_`
2. Add getter: `get name() { return this.name_ ; }`
3. Add setter: `set name(value) { this.name_ = value ; }`
4. Put breakpoint in the setter, and watch the call stack when breakpoint is triggered.

Example for a structure:

**Before:**

```
scope = {
    name:'',
};
```

**After:**

```
scope = {
    name_:'',
    get name() { return this.name_; },
    set name(value) {
        this.name_ = value;
        alert('Changed!');
    },
};
```

I hope this will help you and others!