# AngularJS finding who changed an object watched by $watch

Tags: hover, carousel, callstack, angular-bootstrap, angularjs-watch

I'm using Angular-Bootstrap Carousel directive and making some changes on top of it.
The Carousel had `ng-repeat` for the slides.

I'm trying to get to the next/previous slide by hovering the right/left controls instead of by click.
And achieving that by changing the `object.active` state (previous to false - new to true)

Anyway after a few rounds, all my objects are `active=false` and the carousel displays nothing.
After debugging the array and `$watch` on each object I found that when it goes wrong, is because the directive somehow changes the `active=false` when I don't expect it to.

**Long story short:** Can I somehow get the call stack of an object in the scope I'm watching using `$watch` ?

My watch code is for instance the following:

```
$scope.$watch('requestFilters[0]', function(obj) {
    console.log('Item 0 changed');
}, true);
```

Comment: any luck on this? I also have a similar requirement. "Can I somehow get the call stack of an object in the scope I'm watching using $watch ?"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508197/how-to-find-the-call-site-that-changed-an-object-being-watched